# Intersection of a Convex Polyhedron and a Plane

Tags: convex-optimization, polyhedra, convex-geometry

Let $$X= \{x|a_j^Tx\leq b_j, j=1,...,m \}$$ be a polyhedron, and p is a point inside a polyhedron as shown below. I want to derive an expression for calculating an orthogonal plane from point p which intersect the polyhedron. The orthogonal plane is constructed perpendicular to the trajectory at the considered point, i.e., p

[image]

In other words, this is what I want "**Intersection of a Convex Polyhedron and a Plane**"

[image]

This figure was taken from here: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/IntersectionOfAConvexPolyhedronAndAPlane/

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand where you find a polyhedron:$ \left \| C(x-a) \right \|^2=(x-a)^T(C^TC)(x-a)\le1$ defines in general the interior of an ellipsoid centered in $a$...

Comment: Besides, you have to define to what your "orthogonal plane" is orthogonal to ...

Comment: I don't know what is an orthogonal plane, but that doesn't matter. ***Any*** plane through that point will intersect that polyhedron (or ellipsoid, or whatever it is that you have).

Comment: sorry I updated question a bit (: hope now it's clear ?

Comment: Nope. The polyhedron still looks suspiciously round (in the equation, I mean), and still any plane will do, and if you want the plane to be orthogonal to some trajectory, well, just take the plane orthogonal to the trajectory (there is only one such plane), and it will do as well as any other.

Comment: @IvanNeretin that's what I want, I want to get those intersecting vertices plane and polyhedron

Comment: You haven't reacted to my remark: **it is definitely not a polyhedron** unless you mean $C(x−a)\le 1$ without the squared norm...

Comment: @JeanMarie thank youuu, I updated it :)

Comment: Are you conscious that your condition defines the intersection of 3 half spaces, resulting in a **non-bounded 3 faces polyhedron** (P). But the question remains : you cannot have a plane orthogonal to the 3 bounding planes of (P)...

Comment: @JeanMarie maybe I am wrong, there is no limit about how many half-spaces ti should be. Even one that will be fine. I am sorry if the problem is not clear (:

Comment: @JeanMarie I updated the question, hope now it's clear

Comment: This is a completely different question than with a matrix of coefficients that was $3 \times 3$ !

Comment: Are you sure you need equalities $ c_j^Tx=d_j, j=1,...,p ?$